# Where are the Firefox extensions stored on Mac Snow Leopard?

Tags: mac, firefox, osx-snow-leopard, firefox-extensions

I was wondering where the extensions are stored on Snow Leopard? Google isn't helping at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/[profile name]/extensions`

should be the place